# Tried replacing T8 fluorescent with T8 LED, now fixture won't work

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, fluorescent

I bought a GE T8 17w LED replacement tube that claims to work in existing fixtures with electronic ballast.

I suspect the source of my problem is that I failed to follow the instructions (turn off the lights first).

Nonetheless, because I've always replaced fluorescent tubes with the lights on, that's what I did with the new LED tube. It came on for 1 or 2 seconds, then went out and stayed out. Again, without reading the instructions, I removed a different (working) fluorescent tube and inserted the same LED tube. Again, it came on for 1 or 2 seconds. Both fixtures now fail to work with a standard fluorescent tube.

All the other fixtures on the circuit still work.

So have I destroyed the ballasts or something? Do I need to get new direct-wire fixtures or rewire the existing ones to bypass the ballast? And then get direct-wire LED tubes and return the ones I bought?

And did all this happen because I left the switch on?

[Edit] Seems like the problem was my fault for not turning off the lights first, **but** turns out it was not fatal. After testing the known good fluorescent tube in one of the non-working fixtures, I just left it in place. I turned the lights off for a while and then back on, and the tube lit up. I placed a new fluorescent tube in the other previously non-working fixture, and it also works now. This suggests that the electronic starter/ballast reset itself.

Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm one thing: this almost certainly happened because you left the switch on.

Comment: Unlike other light types LEDs seem to be quite picky about their power.  The incomplete power connection when putting them in might have damage the drivers.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for acknowledging you are the source of your own pain. How does that old saying go, "Twice bitten, thrice shy"? :) TBH, I rarely bother to turn the lights off to replace a bulb and I could get away with it in the incandescent days. With the price of smart bulbs, though, I should probably revisit my policy...

Comment: direct wire usually works a lot better anyway, so return the ones you got and bypass the start/ballast combo that failed.

Comment: After testing the known good fluorescent tube in one of the non-working fixtures, I just left it in place. I turned the lights off for a while and then back on, and the tube lit up. I placed a new fluorescent tube in the other previously non-working fixture, and it also works now. This suggests that the electronic starter/ballast reset itself. I will definitely remember to turn the switch off in the future.

Comment: You tripped some kind of circuit breaker / resettable fuse in the ballast. Good thing it had one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluorescent T8 tubes need something called a starter to operate ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_switch_starter)). Starter is installed in the light fixture, and ensures the correct operation which is **not** continuous 230V AC (or different voltage if you're not in Europe, but still AC).

On the other hand, LED tubes **typically** work on stardard AC, in which case the starter needs to be either replaced with a LED starter (which is just a jumper connecting the two ends of the starter socket), or the starter socket has to be completely bypassed.

**Just be aware that some LED tubes might be different, so it's much needed to consult the documentation!**

You could have destroyed the starter, the LED tubes, or both. If the fluorescent tubes don't work when reinstalled, I bet you destroyed the starters. However, you might have been lucky, because the fluorescent tubes can explode when the starter fails or a wrong starter is used.

**So the right solution is: If you know what you are doing, just replace the starters. If you don't know what you are doing, consult a professional.**

Comment: (For one, I faced this issue in my bathroom mirror lighting, where I couldn't open the lights fixcures to access the starter. I ended up switching to LED strips glued onto the fixture body, and cutting off power to the fixtures completely.)